# (Excel) How to Recompile One Column of Paired Data into Two Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want data stored in one column with pairs to be separated into two columns like this automatically. See that each pair was vertically aligned but is now horizontally aligned. Between two pairs, there is a space cell to separate.

[image]

However, if I simply do two cells manually and then drag down, it gets really messy. In parentheses, I have put which cell the formula actually copies. How can I fix it? Thank you in advance. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your data is in column A.

Enter the following formula into Cell C1:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,3*(ROW()-1)+COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1),1)
```

Fill this formula to the right one column, and then fill both columns down until the data completely appears.
[image]

Comment: One question real quick: why can't you just do `-2` instead of `-COLUMN($B$1)`?

Comment: Because if you insert a column on the left, the column($B$2) might get adjusted to column($C$2) and the formula will still work.  Having a 2 there would fail in that case.

Comment: Actually slightly more flexible would be column($C$2)-1, that would handle inserting a column between B and C.